# validator rules for a database select / dropdownmenu (in a form) laravel 4.1

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, laravel-4, validation

I have a problem with laravel, and my form.

In my form (createBand.blade.php), i made a form with a **dropdownlist** wich call a database table: musicalGenre.

It should be noted that the dropdownmenu/list (select form) calls to **another table** in the database called **MusicalGenre**, and the form where I want the dropdownlist is to register a band in the database table **Bands**.

The select form works, i could choose in a dropdownlist all musicalGenre_name in my table after seeding them. Here's the blade page code (of course i have open, close the form and the section like laravel requires):

```
    <p>
    {{Form::label('name','Name of the Band: ')}}
    {{Form::text('name',Input::old('name'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('name'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('name')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
    {{Form::label('email','Band Email: ')}}
    {{Form::text('email',Input::old('email'))}}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('email'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('email')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>

<p>
    {{Form::label('musicalGenre','your style: ')}}
    {{Form::select('musicalGenre_name', $genre_options = array('' => 'select your style') + musicalGenre::lists('name'), Input::old('musicalGenre_name')) }}
</p>
@if ($errors->has('musicalGenre'))
<p class='error'> {{ $errors->first('musicalGenre_name')}}</p>
@endif
<br>
<br>
```

I have a controller named createBandController, where i made some rules for validators for the blade form. The poblem is:
i can't **pass the validators**, that is to say, even if i choose a musical genre in my dropdownlist, for laravel there no choice made.

I have the error "musical genre is required". **I don't understand the validator rules for a select form in my controller**, or i don't know what i'm suposed **to input in the rules for musical genre**. Here's the controller code:

```
public function createBand() {
        $result = MusicalGenre::all();
        $genre = $result->lists('name');

        $inputs = Input::all();
        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'required|between:1,64|unique:bands,name',
            'email' => 'between:1,128|email|unique:bands,email',
            'musicalGenre' => 'integer|required|in:musicalGenre'
        );

        $validation = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('createBand')->withInput()->withErrors($validation)
                            ->with('alert_error', 'you have some mistakes');
```

**Don't pay attention to the names**, (i'm french, i changed them in order to be clear for you), and i'm sure that is the validator of my dropdownlist who make problems when i fill out my form, because i can't pass it.  In my **original project code**, there are **no spelling mistakes**.

All my validators and variable names work. **I think i need to find the correct rules for a select form input and validators in order to laravel knows i made a choice when i choose in my dropdownlist.**

At first i thought to **specify** that the dropdownlist use the **database table musicalGenre**. Like i specified that some **fields** are in the database table **Bands**, like this:

```
'name' => 'required|between:1,64|unique:bands,name'
```

Here, "name" is a field of the database table Bands. But it didn't work too.

If anyone have a solutions or wants to help, i'm interested.
Thank you *(and sorry if my english seems so bad)*.

Comment: In your code the name of the select is `musicalGenre_name` but you are checking for `name` in your rules. Have you tried to change this?

Comment: @AntoineAugusti. In fact,name in my rules is the name of the band (rules for another label and another validator in my form who doesn't appear here). I change/fix that in order to you understand. So the problem does not come from there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation rule in: on the field musicalGenre won't work the way that you have implemented it. It expects a comma delimited list of strings which the field value is scrubbed against.

For example if the field was `'Gender'` the validation would be:

```
'gender' => 'in:male,female'
```

To validate against musicalGenre against a model you will need to write a custom Validator. See http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

I am currently writing a custom validator for this `'belongs_to'` validation and when I have it working I'll post it here.

**UPDATE**

I have written a custom validation rule that should help. Firstly create a `validators.php` file and include it in `global.php`

```
require app_path().'/validators.php';
```

Within `validators.php` create the custom rule:

```
Validator::extend('exists_in', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
  $result = $parameters[0]::find($value);
  return ($result == null) ? FALSE : TRUE;
});
```

In your validations you could now have:

```
'musicalGenre' => 'integer|required|exists_in:musicalGenre'
```

The exists_in validation takes a parameter of the Model Class name

And to give this validation an error message, add the following to the array in `app/lang/en/validation.php`:

```
"exists_in" => "The selected :attribute is invalid."
```

Comment: @david Thank you a ot, i'll search for a solution too. When i'll found something i'll post it here.

Comment: I think you meant to say thanks to @joeturner. I merely edited the response.

Comment: @joeturner does it worked for you? i tried your way, exactly how you told me, but it does not work.

Comment: @Julien I've just had another look over your code and it looks like you haven't got the ID of the Genre pulling through to set the value in the select. Try `{{Form::select('musicalGenre_name', $genre_options = array('' => 'select your style') + musicalGenre::lists('name', 'id'), Input::old('musicalGenre_name')) }}`

Comment: @Julien when you say it does not work. What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: @joeturner It's perfect in fact, like i said in the update, i have to make the model classe and not the tble database name.

Answer (score 0):

Does exists:musicalGenre instead of in:musicalGenre help?

Comment: No it doesn't change anything, i can't pass the validator.